# I have a Toshiba Satellite ES5018 in which the battery meter disappeared

Tags: windows-7, toshiba-laptop

Have Toshiba Satellite ES5018 on which the battery meter disappeared and I can't figure out how to get it back on

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking on the system tray and select properties. You should see an On/Off for different indicators[image]